# Any way to get LOTW "credit" for a paper QSL card?

Tags: qsl-card, etiquette, lotw

I have some QSOs with hams who will send paper QSL cards but do not use LOTW.

I know that if I manage to get a paper card from them I can submit it to ARRL for DXCC credit. But will that QSL show up in LOTW?  Or is there zero integration between LOTW and paper confirms?  (It would be nice if it would show up in LOTW so I could have a single view of all ARRL award credits and so I can get credit in QRZ, which will honor LOTW confirms).

(Relating to submitting cards to ARRL for credit -- do you get the cards back eventually? Also, as long as you're willing to throw in a little extra cash, is it OK etiquette to ask a ham to send two identical QSL cards?  The idea is that for a rare or interesting place I'd have one card that would always stay at home and one that would be submitted to ARRL.  That way even if ARRL/USPS lost the card I'd still have the other one for my collection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is!  You have two options, you can either mail your cards to the ARRL for verification, or you could meet up with a QSL Award Manager.  Each section has one or more QSL Award Managers who do exactly this.

http://www.arrl.org/awards-managers

Comment: So just to make sure I understand -- these award managers are able to somehow enter the QSL card data into LOTW (and not just my DXCC account) so that my side of the QSO -- the info **I** uploaded to LOTW -- will be able to show up as a confirmed QSO within LOTW?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.